# Custom Annotations for JPA MappedSuperClass to avoid extending

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * Created by abhinav on 24/02/17.
*/
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class PersistentObject implements Serializable {

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version = 0;

    @Column(name = "updatetime")
    private Long updateTime;

    @Column(name = "createtime")
    private Long createTime= new Date().getTime();

   @PrePersist
   @PreUpdate
   void updateTime() {
       this.updateTime = new Date().getTime();
   }

}
```

When i want my entity to include the fields from PersistentObject I have to extend this superclass, Instead of this i was hoping to have a custom annotation mechanism, lets say called by "CustomAnnotation" which i can use on my entities to include the above fields without extending PersistentObject.
Is there a way to do this, Please point in the right direction.

Comment: No, that doesn't exist. But you could avoid extending by using an Embedded field instead.

Comment: Not without using some form of build/run-time bytecode enhancement.